# Android Spinner Not Populating | Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, spinner

I'm pretty new to android and kotlin so please excuse what may be a very simple problem to solve!

I've created a basic app using the Navigation Architecture Component, using the bottom nav bar with three navigation options. Each navigation option points to a dedicate fragment which displays a text box only. So far so good, this all works correctly.

On one of the fragments (fragement_record.xml/RecordFragmet.kt), I'm trying to load a single spinner which I want to populate from a string-array which is defined in my strings.xml file. When I build and run the app it works without any errors yet the spinner, which is visible, contains no data - it's empty.

I've researched Stack Overflow, and many other sites, but it's not clear what I'm doing wrong.

My string array is shown below:

```
<string-array name="shot_type_values">
    <item>Select shot type…</item>
    <item>Tee</item>
    <item>Approach</item>
    <item>Short</item>
    <item>Putt</item>
</string-array>
```

My layout file, fragment_record.xml is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RecordFragment">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/shot_type"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorText"
        android:minHeight="70dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</FrameLayout>
```

My activity file, RecordFragment.kt is shown below:

```
package digitalaidconsulting.com.proshotpoc

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Spinner
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_record.*

class RecordFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val shotType = view?.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.shot_type)
        this.context?.let {
            ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                it,
                R.array.shot_type_values,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
            ).also { adapter ->
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                if (shotType != null) {
                    shotType.adapter = adapter
                }
            }
        }

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_record, container, false)

    }
}
```

This is the end result after the build has successfully run (emulator):

[image: screenshot of empty spinner after app load]

All help gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view is not yet inflated at this point.

You can move your code to onViewCreated method or use view created in a following way:

```
   override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_record, container, false)
        val shotType = view?.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.shot_type)
        this.context?.let {
            ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                it,
                R.array.shot_type_values,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
            ).also { adapter ->
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                if (shotType != null) {
                    shotType.adapter = adapter
                }
            }
        }
        return view
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @sebastian. This worked perfectly. Appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code: -

```
var adapter =  ArrayAdapter<String>(it, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, yourArrayList);
shotType.adapter = adapter
```

Note: Also, please move the code to `onViewCreated()` overridden method.

Comment: Thanks @shalu. Appreciate the quick response.